# Carry forward NA values for multiple columns R

Tags: r, loops, na, zoo

I need to carry forward NA values from one column to the next. An example of the code is below

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
           b =c(NA,NA,3,4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
           c = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,5,6,NA,NA,NA,NA),
           d = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,7,8,NA,NA),
           e = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,9,10))
```

I have tried to use a loop with the `na.locf` function in `zoo` but this only carries the previous columns values

```
columns <- seq(2,ncol(df))
output <- list()
for (i in columns){
  output[[i]] <- t(zoo::na.locf(t(df[,(i-1):i])))[,2]
}
```

The expected output would be like

```
expected_output <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
           b = c(1,2,3,4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
           c = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,NA,NA,NA,NA),
           d = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,NA,NA),
           e = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transpose `df`, apply `na.locf`, transpose again and replace `df` contents with that to make it a data frame with the correct names.

```
library(zoo)

out <- replace(df, TRUE, t(na.locf(t(df), fill = NA)))
identical(out, expected_output)
## [1] TRUE
```

This also works and is similar except it applies `na.locf0` to each row instead of applying `na.locf` to the transpose.

```
out <- replace(df, TRUE, t(apply(df, 1, na.locf0)))
identical(out, expected_output)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Perfect, much simpler than what I was trying!